# How the spectrum changes after removing a line from a symmetric positive definite the matrix?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, positive-definite

I have a symmetric positive definite matrix $A$ and a diagonal matrix $P$ with $1$ or $0$ on the diagonal. Knowing the spectrum of $A$, there exists some result that helps in estimation of the spectrum of $PA$ (or $AP$)? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If the matrices $A$ and $P$ are commutable it holds that the product of their spectra equals the spectrum of their product.

Comment: ah good to know but it isn't the case, thx

Answer (score 0):

We note that the eigenvalues of $PA$ are given by the poles of $[z-PA]^{-1}$
. Note further that $P$ is an orthogonal projection operator. Thus we can
use the Feshbach projection formula ($Q=1-P$ )
\begin{eqnarray*}
\lbrack z-H]^{-1}
&=&[z-QHQ]^{-1}Q+\{P+[z-QHQ]^{-1}QHPR_{P}(z)\{P+PHQ[z-QHQ]^{-1}\} \\
R_{P}(z) &=&P[z-H]^{-1}P=[z-PHP-PHQ[z-QHQ]^{-1}QHP]^{-1}P
\end{eqnarray*}
to arrive at
\begin{eqnarray*}
\lbrack z-PA]^{-1}
&=&[z-QPAQ]^{-1}Q+\{P+[z-QPAQ]^{-1}QPAPR_{P}(z)\{P+PPAQ[z-QPAQ]^{-1}\} \\
&=&\frac{1}{z}Q+PR_{P}(z)\{P+\frac{1}{z}PAQ\} \\
R_{P}(z) &=&P[z-PA]^{-1}P=[z-PAP-PPAQ[z-QPAQ]^{-1}QPAP]^{-1}P=[z-PAP]^{-1}
\end{eqnarray*}
Hence
\begin{equation*}
\lbrack z-PA]^{-1}=\frac{1}{z}Q+P[z-PAP]^{-1}\{P+\frac{1}{z}PAQ\}
\end{equation*}
and its singularities are $z=0$ and the poles of $[z-PAP]^{-1}$, i.e., the
eigenvalues of $PAP$. From this, further expressions for the
eigenprojectors of $PA$ can be obtained, see Kato,  "Perturbation theory
for linear operators ", Chapter 1 on finite dimensional vector spaces.

Comment: thank you, it is a bit complicated but works. In the meantime I found another argument

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. First, we have some eigenvalues $\lambda=0$ since $PA$ is singular. Suppose now $\lambda\neq 0$ and $v$ its associated eigenvector. So $\lambda v=PAv$. At a line $i$ where $P_{ii}=0$ we obtain $\lambda v_i=0$, meaning $v_i=0$. So $Pv=v$ and $\lambda v=PAPv$, thus $(\lambda,v)$ is a eigen pair of $PAP$ as well. Similarly if $(\lambda,v)$ is an eigen pair of $PAP$ it is for $PA$.